# How to add a .js into a file in c#

Tags: c#

Okay so I'm working with c# winforms and I have this code so far to create a ReadMe.txt and the folder itself

```
string folderName = @"C:\Test";
        string text = "This is used Test.";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(folderName))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
            File.Create(@"C:\Test\ReadMe.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\ReadMe.txt", text);
            //Need to add Test.js to the folder C:\Test Here
        }
```

As you can see above I need to add the Test.js to the folder.

Please and Thank you.

(P.S Yes it is added as a resource already)

Comment: you mean you have a file in your Debug directory named "Test.js" which you want to copy to the directory in this case "C:\Test"?

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a slight bug on line 3.  It is using File.Exists instead of Directory.Exists to test if the Test Folder exists.

```
string folderName = @"C:\Test";

if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
}

string readMeFileName = Path.Combine(folderName, "ReadMe.txt");
string text = "This is used Test.";
File.WriteAllText(readMeFileName , text);

string jsFileName = Path.Combine(folderName, "Test.JS");
File.Copy("Test.js", jsFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

[File.Copy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.